# What does an addict consume?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that can be used to mean "the thing that this addict is addicted to"?

An addict has addiction, which drives them to consume their "______"?

*Addiction Target*?

---

By comparison: A Manager manages their *managee*.

Comment: I'd say substance if it's a substance. Otherwise their vice or habit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*addictive* is usually used as an adjective, but works as a noun, too:

> addictive (plural addictives)
>
> 1. A drug that causes an addiction.
> 2. Anything that is very habit-forming.

<sub>(source: [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/addictive#Noun))</sub>

Comment: Huh .. did not know that was a thing. Will leave 24 hrs on principle, feel free to ping me here if I forget to come back and accept.

Comment: @Brondahl With all respect to Wiktionary.org (I think it's doing a fine job), it is a very permissive dictionary. It's the dictionary that lists words when none of the other common "authoritative" (scare quotes) dictionaries do. By those I mean, Oxford, Merriam-Webster, American Heritage, Collins, Cambridge, Macmillan, Random House, Longman etc.